# Vector Error and Other (Noob C++)

Tags: c++11

I am learning vectors and have encountered 2 errors in my code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Vector Example";
    vector<int> v = {5,7,9,4,5,8};
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
        cout << v[i] << '\n';
}
```

Makefile:

```
main: booksource.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g booksource.cpp -o booksource
```

for header file please refer to http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h

First error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:1869:5: error: template-id ‘do_get<>’ for ‘String std::messages<char>::do_get(std::messages_base::catalog, int, int, const String&) const’ does not match any template declaration
 messages<char>::do_get(catalog, int, int, const string&) const;
 ^
```

Second Error:

```
booksource.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
booksource.cpp:5:29: error: could not convert ‘{5, 7, 9, 4, 5, 8}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Vector<int>’
 vector<int> v = {5,7,9,4,5,8};
```

Comment: What does `g++ --version` say?

Comment: g++ (Debian 4.9.2-16) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: That header redefines vector to its own std::vector subclass (`Vector` with upper-case V). Very bad style to me. That's important to know when trying to make sense of the code and error message.

Comment: I'd be tempted to start with a more standard way of including system headers: `#include <vector>` and `#include <iostream>` in your case.

Comment: If you want to learn actual C++, I'd not include that header and try to use std::vector instead (and do as @quamrana suggests). I'm slightly appalled by that header, I can't believe it's from Stroustrup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the second error message with 4.7.2, where `std::vector` doesn't have a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`. I don't know how this could happen with 4.9.

Personally, I would stay very far away from that header. I understand Stroustrup himself seems to have written it, but it basically does everything that a typical textbook would say not to do in the first chapter.

Comment: Would including the header ( and the `#define` ) have the problem of making every instance of `std::vector` become `std::Vector` (with a capital V), which doesn't exist?

Comment: Only past the point where the `#define` is. There are no more includes in the header, so this is not a problem. Well, it _is_ a problem, but it is not the OP's problem.

Comment: Ok well I got the program to run.  Thanks everyone for your input.  Thread can be closed.